# How can we calculate the ionization energy of lithium atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, ionization-energy

In Griffiths book, I have seen how to calculate the ionization energy of a Helium atom, but I am unable to calculate it for a Lithium atom. How can we calculate the ionization energy of a Lithium atom?

Comment: The lithium **atom** or the $\textrm{Li}^{2+}$ ion? There is no simple ay to calculate the ionisation energy of any atom or ion containing more than one electron.

Comment: Is measurement an option or by "calculate" you mean a theoretical approach?

Comment: @Newbie theoritical.